# ld unknown option -platform_version while installing perl package

Tags: perl, makefile, clang, macos-mojave, dbd-pg

I am trying to install perl package DBD::Pg in my macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6. But I get error for unknown option -platform_version and does not allow make command to continue. How would I be able to solve this? Thank you!

The following is the error I observe

```
ld: unknown option: -platform_version
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.bundle] Error 1
```

ld version

```
ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-450.3
BUILD 18:16:53 Apr  5 2019
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 10.0.1, (clang-1001.0.46.4) (static support for 22, runtime is 22)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 10.0.1 (tapi-1001.0.4.1)
```

clang version

```
clang -v
clang version 10.0.0 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/macuser/miniconda3/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on macOS 10.15.5, perlbrew perl 5.30.1.

- First I installed PostgreSQL version 12.3 from
  https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads
- Downloaded the perl module DBD::Pg tarball https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/T/TU/TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-3.13.0.tar.gz
- Installed the package:

  ```
  $ POSTGRES_HOME=/Library/PostgreSQL/12 perl Makefile.PL
  Configuring DBD::Pg 3.13.0
  PostgreSQL version: 120003 (default port: 5432)
  POSTGRES_HOME: /Library/PostgreSQL/12
  POSTGRES_INCLUDE: /Library/PostgreSQL/12/include
  POSTGRES_LIB: /Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib
  OS: darwin
  Checking if your kit is complete...
  Looks good
  Using DBI 1.643 (for perl 5.030001 on darwin-2level) installed in /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-2level/auto/DBI/
  Generating a Unix-style Makefile
  Writing Makefile for DBD::Pg
  Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

  $ make
  cp Pg.pm blib/lib/DBD/Pg.pm
  cp lib/Bundle/DBD/Pg.pm blib/lib/Bundle/DBD/Pg.pm
  Running Mkbootstrap for Pg ()
  chmod 644 "Pg.bs"
  "/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Pg.bs blib/arch/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.bs 644
  "/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/bin/perl" -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/Pg/g; s/^do\(/dontdo\(/" /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-2level/auto/DBI/Driver.xst > Pg.xsi
  "/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/bin/perl" "/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/ExtUtils/typemap'  Pg.xs > Pg.xsc
  mv Pg.xsc Pg.c
  cc -c  -I/Library/PostgreSQL/12/include -I/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-2level/auto/DBI -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -DPGLIBVERSION=120003 -DPGDEFPORT=5432 -O3  -DPERL_EXTMALLOC_DEF -Dmalloc=Perl_malloc -Dfree=Perl_mfree -Drealloc=Perl_realloc -Dcalloc=Perl_calloc -DVERSION=\"3.13.0\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.13.0\"  "-I/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/darwin-2level/CORE"   Pg.c
  cc -c  -I/Library/PostgreSQL/12/include -I/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-2level/auto/DBI -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -DPGLIBVERSION=120003 -DPGDEFPORT=5432 -O3  -DPERL_EXTMALLOC_DEF -Dmalloc=Perl_malloc -Dfree=Perl_mfree -Drealloc=Perl_realloc -Dcalloc=Perl_calloc -DVERSION=\"3.13.0\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.13.0\"  "-I/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/darwin-2level/CORE"   dbdimp.c
  cc -c  -I/Library/PostgreSQL/12/include -I/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-2level/auto/DBI -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -DPGLIBVERSION=120003 -DPGDEFPORT=5432 -O3  -DPERL_EXTMALLOC_DEF -Dmalloc=Perl_malloc -Dfree=Perl_mfree -Drealloc=Perl_realloc -Dcalloc=Perl_calloc -DVERSION=\"3.13.0\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.13.0\"  "-I/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/darwin-2level/CORE"   quote.c
  cc -c  -I/Library/PostgreSQL/12/include -I/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-2level/auto/DBI -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -DPGLIBVERSION=120003 -DPGDEFPORT=5432 -O3  -DPERL_EXTMALLOC_DEF -Dmalloc=Perl_malloc -Dfree=Perl_mfree -Drealloc=Perl_realloc -Dcalloc=Perl_calloc -DVERSION=\"3.13.0\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.13.0\"  "-I/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/darwin-2level/CORE"   types.c
  rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.bundle
  LD_RUN_PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib" cc  -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong  Pg.o dbdimp.o quote.o types.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.bundle  \
       -L/Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib -lpq -lm   \

  chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.bundle
  Manifying 2 pod documents

  $ make test

  "/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
  t/00_signature.t ....... skipped: Set the environment variable TEST_SIGNATURE to enable this test
  t/00basic.t ............ ok
  t/01connect.t .......... Please wait, creating new database (version 12.3) for testing
  t/01connect.t .......... 1/15 #
  # DBI                         Version 1.643
  # DBD::Pg                     Version 3.13.0
  # Perl                        Version 5.30.1
  # OS                          darwin
  # PostgreSQL (compiled)       120003
  # PostgreSQL (target)         120300
  # PostgreSQL (reported)       PostgreSQL 12.3 on x86_64-apple-darwin, compiled by Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn), 64-bit
  # Default port                5432
  # DBI_DSN                     dbi:Pg:db="postgres";port=5440;host=<pwd>/dbdpg_test_database/data/socket
  # DBI_USER                    hakonhaegland
  # Test schema                 dbd_pg_testschema
  # LANG                        C
  # Adjusted:                   initdb
  t/01connect.t .......... ok
  t/01constants.t ........ ok
  t/02attribs.t .......... ok
  t/03dbmethod.t ......... ok
  t/03smethod.t .......... ok
  t/04misc.t ............. ok
  t/06bytea.t ............ ok
  t/07copy.t ............. ok
  t/08async.t ............ ok
  t/09arrays.t ........... ok
  t/10_pg_error_field.t .. ok
  t/12placeholders.t ..... ok
  t/20savepoints.t ....... ok
  t/30unicode.t .......... ok
  t/99cleanup.t .......... ok
  All tests successful.
  Files=17, Tests=2908, 31 wallclock secs ( 0.55 usr  0.11 sys +  5.99 cusr  2.38 csys =  9.03 CPU)
  Result: PASS

  $ make install
  "/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Pg.bs blib/arch/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.bs 644
  Manifying 2 pod documents
  Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
  Installing /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-2level/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.bundle
  Installing /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-2level/Bundle/DBD/Pg.pm
  Installing /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/site_perl/5.30.1/darwin-2level/DBD/Pg.pm
  Installing /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/man/man3/Bundle::DBD::Pg.3
  Installing /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/man/man3/DBD::Pg.3
  Appending installation info to /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.1/lib/5.30.1/darwin-2level/perllocal.pod
  ```

My compiler version is:

```
$ cc --version
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Did the tests pass for you? https://github.com/bucardo/dbdpg/issues/69 . I also found that the EnterpriseDB pre-built package didn't work for me:  https://github.com/mojolicious/minion/issues/97

Comment: @briandfoy Yes all tests pass, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @briandfoy , I got problems in the tests. I followed the thread and could successfully install the module.

Comment: ah, I see Håkon didn't enable SSL. That's where the linking gets weird.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my Xcode and got clang version 11.0.3 Then I had problems in 'make install' command. I could solve that using the suggestions from the thread https://github.com/bucardo/dbdpg/issues/69 @briandfoy posted. Thank you very much!